# How to add an additional condition in left join using query builder using Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have this Eloquent Query Builder in Laravel-5.8:

```
$userCompany         = Auth::user()->company_id;    
$userEmployee        = Auth::user()->employee_id;
$employeeCode        = Auth::user()->employee_code;
$employeeemptypeid   = HrEmployee::where('employee_code', $employeeCode)
                            ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                            ->pluck('employee_type_id')->first();
$employeeegendercode = HrEmployee::where('employee_code', $employeeCode)
                            ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
                            ->pluck('gender_code')->first(); 

$leaveBalance = DB::table('hr_leave_types AS lt')
                    ->leftJoin('hr_leave_type_details AS ltd', function($join) use ($userCompany) {
                        $join->on('ltd.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
                            ->where('ltd.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                            ->where('ltd.employee_type_id', '=', $employeeemptypeid);
                    })
                    ->leftJoin('hr_leave_requests AS lr', function($join) use ($userCompany, $userEmployee) {
                        $join->on('lr.leave_type_id', '=', 'lt.id')
                            ->where('lr.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                            ->where('lr.employee_id', '=', $userEmployee)
                            ->whereYear('lr.commencement_date', '=', date('Y'))
                            ->where('lr.leave_status', 4);
                    })                        
                    ->leftJoin('hr_employees AS e', function($join) use ($userCompany, $userEmployee) {
                        $join->on('e.id', '=', 'lr.employee_id')
                            ->where('e.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                            ->where('e.id', '=', $userEmployee)
                            ->where('e.employee_type_id', '=', 'ltd.employee_type_id');
                    })
                    ->where('lt.company_id', '=', $userCompany)
                    ->select(
                        'lt.leave_type_name as leaveCategory',
                        'ltd.no_of_days as applicableLeave',
                        DB::raw("IFNULL(SUM(lr.no_of_days),0) as approvedLeave")
                    )
                    ->groupBy('lt.leave_type_name', 'e.id')
                    ->get();
```

This is used to get the Employee Leave Balance. It was working fine till this point.

But there are some leave types that belong to only male, only female and some to both genders.

How do I add this to the query above:

```
if($employeeegendercode == 0) 
{
    $leavetypes = HrLeaveType::join('hr_leave_type_details', 'hr_leave_type_details.leave_type_id', '=', 'hr_leave_types.id')
                    ->select('hr_leave_types.id as id', 'hr_leave_types.leave_type_name')
                    ->where('hr_leave_types.company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->where('hr_leave_type_details.employee_type_id', $employeeemptypeid)
                    ->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 3])
                    ->get();
}else{
    $leavetypes = HrLeaveType::join('hr_leave_type_details', 'hr_leave_type_details.leave_type_id', '=', 'hr_leave_types.id')
                    ->select('hr_leave_types.id as id', 'hr_leave_types.leave_type_name')
                    ->where('hr_leave_types.company_id', $userCompany)
                    ->where('hr_leave_type_details.employee_type_id', $employeeemptypeid)
                    ->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 2])
                    ->get();
}
```

especially for:

```
hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 3]
```

and

```
hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 2]
```

Thanks

Comment: You need `join` or `left join`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `when()` query builder function.

```php
    /**
     * Apply the callback's query changes if the given "value" is true.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  callable  $callback
     * @param  callable|null  $default
     * @return mixed|$this
     */
    public function when($value, $callback, $default = null)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return $callback($this, $value) ?: $this;
        } elseif ($default) {
            return $default($this, $value) ?: $this;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Here are a couple of example from the docs:

```php
// If $request->input('role') is truthy (in this context, it's not null),
// then filter users using $role variable.
$role = $request->input('role');

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
                    return $query->where('role_id', $role);
                })
                ->get();
```

```php
// If $sortBy isn't null, order by $sortBy
// if $sortBy is null, order by 'name'
$sortBy = null;

$users = DB::table('users')
                ->when($sortBy, function ($query, $sortBy) {
                    return $query->orderBy($sortBy);
                }, function ($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy('name');
                })
                ->get();
```

Applying this to your example, I guess you'd have the following:

```php
$leavetypes = HrLeaveType::join('hr_leave_type_details', 'hr_leave_type_details.leave_type_id', '=', 'hr_leave_types.id')
    ->select('hr_leave_types.id as id', 'hr_leave_types.leave_type_name')
    ->where('hr_leave_types.company_id', $userCompany)
    ->where('hr_leave_type_details.employee_type_id', $employeeemptypeid)
    ->when(
        $employeeegendercode == 0,
        function ($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 3]);
        },
        function ($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 2]);
        }
    )
    ->get();
```

I exagerated the indentation a bit to make it clear. For relatively small changes like this you could use PHP 7.4's shorthand closures.

```php
->when(
    $employeeegendercode == 0,
    fn ($query) => $query->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 3]),
    fn ($query) => $query->whereIn('hr_leave_type_details.leave_applicable_gender', [1, 2])
)
```

More on the subject
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses